# A question involving chiral transformations and gamma matrices

Tags: field-theory, spinors, dirac-matrices, chirality

I'm looking at a calculation that involves an infinitesimal transformation of a Dirac fermion field:

$$\Psi \rightarrow e^{i \beta \gamma^5} \Psi.$$

Then the conjugate field $\bar{\Psi} = \Psi^{\dagger} \gamma^0$ transforms as $\bar{\Psi} \rightarrow (e^{i \beta \gamma^5} \Psi)^\dagger \gamma^0$. Then from here we get:

$$\Psi^\dagger e^{-i \beta \gamma^5} \gamma^0.$$

So far I understand the steps, but I don't how from here one jumps to
$$\Psi^\dagger \gamma^0 e^{i \beta \gamma^5}.$$

Why does the sign in the exponential changes and the gamma matrix is suddenly on the right?

Comment: Try expanding the exponential to its series and apply the anti-commutation relation to pull the $\gamma_0$ to the left of the exponential series.

Comment: @Hannes, It's maybe better if you promote your comment to an answer. Of course, if your time permits.

Comment: When you commute $\gamma^0$ past any function of $\gamma^5$, you obtain the very *same* function of  $-\gamma^5$, instead. Can you prove that? No expansions.

Comment: @CosmasZachos That is not true for any function. Try pulling $\gamma_0$ through $\gamma_1\gamma_5$ or most other multiplications of $\gamma_5$ with a matrix that is non-commuting with $\gamma_0$.

Comment: Fair enough, any function of *just* $\gamma ^5$, without further noncommuting matrices, as in the question. Works for braiding past just  $\gamma ^5$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one usually does, write the exponential term with a power series expansion,
$$\Psi^{\dagger} \big(1 - i \beta \gamma^{5} + \mathcal{O}(\beta^2) \big) \gamma^0$$
then using the anticommutative properties $\{\gamma^5,\gamma^{\mu} \} = 0$ you can move $\gamma^{0}$ through the $\gamma^{5}$ terms, picking up a minus sign in the process. You can check the higher order terms too.

Edit: I see this has also already been pointed out in the comments by Hannes too.